# How to convert a number to Indian numbering format in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to show number 100 000 000 in [Indian numbering format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) by using this code, but i get result as 100,000,000.00 instead of 10,00,00,000.00

```
DecimalFormat finalCellFormater = new DecimalFormat("##,##,###,##0");
formatter.format(new BigDecimal("100000000"));
```

Comment: `NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();` *or* use [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/).

Comment: From the documentation we have  `The grouping size is a constant number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####".`

Comment: Also be aware that you code is defining a formatter (finalCellFormater) and using another (formatter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://icu.unicode.org/

```java
Format format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));

System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("99999999")));
```

which returns `Rs 99,99,99,999.00`